# Accounts.forgotPassword/Email error: "forgotPassword" Error: Greeting never received

Tags: meteor

So I'm not using the generic `Accounts-ui` package and am configuring a password recovery system. So far, so good...until the error below showed up:

[image]

I know it's an error with my smtp setup in `/sever/smtp.js`, which reads like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
    username: 'myEmail%40gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 25
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://myEmail%40gmail.com:' + encodeURIComponent('password') + "@smtp.gmail.com:25";
});
```

I guess you can completely ignore the `smtp` object above, since I had to manually change the `process.env.MAIL_URL` variable because I had another error before this. This entire process is set up on my local computer/localhost.

I had port 465 before this and there was an error where the username and password were not found. I changed to port 25 and the process worked until I got this error saying that the greeting was never received.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Edit: I would also like to add that adding the email package and changing up the ports messes up the `Accounts.createUser` function, where Meteor is unable to create a user unless I remove the smtp setup from the server.

Answer (score 2):

I am  noob in Meteor, but the below did work for me .

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
    username: 'myEmail',   // eg: myEmail@gmail.com
    password: 'password,   // eg: password for your email
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',  // gmail smtp
    port: 25
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

Let me know if this worked

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I still get the same "greeting never received" error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps but:

You can use `@` instead of `%40`

Answer (score 2):

This is work with me in localhost and Digital Ocean

```
/*Send Email Through Gmail SMTP*/
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://gmailUsername:gmailPassword@smtp.gmail.com:587";
```

Let me know if you still have greeting problem

Anyway, you don't need `Meteor.startup`. You only need to place it somewhere on your server folder. For example: `server/email.js`